Let $A=\langle\{a_1,\dots,a_k\}\rangle,B=\langle\{b_1,\dots,b_k\}\rangle(ord(a_i)=ord(b_i), i=1,\dots,k)$. If $|A| = |B|$, are $A$ and $B$ isomorphic?
Let $A=\langle\{a_1,\dots,a_k\}\rangle,B=\langle\{b_1,\dots,b_k\}\rangle$ where $a_i$ and $b_i$ are elements of some group and $ord(a_i)=ord(b_i), i=1,\dots,k$. In general, if $|A| = |B|$, are the groups $A$ and $B$ isomorphic?
I'm trying to figure out what generator sets to pick, so that the generated finite groups would be isomorphic. I'm trying to understand the relationship between isomorphic groups and their generator sets. I know that in general, if two groups have the same number of elements they don't have to be isomorphic. So it's only a necessary condition. So I'm trying to impose some conditions on the generator sets so that they do generate isomorphic groups.

All dihedral groups are generated by two elements of order $2$.

No. Take for example $G=(\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z})\times S_3$, where $S_3$ is the symmetric group on the set $\{1,2,3\}$. Let $a_1=(3,1)$, $a_2=(2,1)$, $b_1=(0,(1\; 2))$ and $b_2=(0,(1\; 2\; 3))$.
Then $A=\langle a_1,a_2\rangle = \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}\times \{1\}$ and $B=\langle b_1,b_2\rangle = \{0\}\times S_3$, so both subgroups have order $6$, and $\mathrm{ord}(a_1)=\mathrm{ord}(b_1)=2$ and $\mathrm{ord}(a_2)=\mathrm{ord}(b_2)=3$. But the two subgroups given are non isomorphic since $A$ is abelian and the $B$ nonabelian.
If you are interested in see the isomorphism of groups in terms of generators, the order of elements is, in general, not sufficient, you need to see the relations between generators. I suggest you to look for presentations of groups.

Thanks! Do you know if group representation theory is applicable in computational problems? More specifically, given two sets $X$ and $Y$ ($X \cap Y = \emptyset$) that are not known beforehand.  I want to compute subsets $A \subset X$ and $B \subset Y$ so that the groups generated by $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic.

@H-a-y-K I meant "presentation" of groups. Computational algebra is not my area at all, but maybe you can find something useful by looking at the Schreier-Sims algorithm or the Todd-Coxeter algorithm. As far a I understand these do not compute group generators in general, but maybe you can find useful references by looking at them. Also, maybe is useful if you look for the word problem for groups. Hope that helps
